# Training Stanford CoreNLP co-reference

Tags: stanford-nlp

I would like to use the Stanford CoreNLP library to do co-referencing in Dutch.

My question is, how do I train the CoreNLP to handle Dutch co-referencing resolution?

We've already created a Dutch NER model based on the 'conll2002' set (https://github.com/WillemJan/Stanford_ner_bugreport/raw/master/dutch.gz), but we would also like to use the co-referencing module in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the class edu.stanford.nlp.scoref.StatisticalCorefTrainer.

The appropriate properties file for English is in:

edu/stanford/nlp/scoref/properties/scoref-train-conll.properties

You may have to get the latest code base from GitHub:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP

While we are not currently supporting training of the statistical coreference models in the toolkit, I do believe the code for training them is included and it is certainly possible it works right now.  I have yet to verify if it is functioning properly.

Please let me know if you need any more assistance.  If you encounter bugs I can try to fix them...we would definitely like to get the statistical coreference training operational for future releases!